# Wireless card not detected... sometimes

Tags: wireless, 14.04

I am usiong Ubuntu 14.04 amd64.

Today, I started having problems with my wireless card (manufactured by TP-Link, I don't remember the exact model). The system didn't detect it (it wasn't displayed after using lshw -C network). After two reboots, it appeared, but then, after shutting down the computer and starting it again sometime later, the problem repeated itself. This time, one reboot was sufficient to make it work.

When it is detected, its' description in lshw -C network output is the following:

```
  *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR2417 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5007G 802.11bg]
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:05:02.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: 00:27:19:c3:35:b2
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath5k driverversion=3.13.0-24-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.101 latency=168 link=yes maxlatency=28 mingnt=10 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
   resources: irq:23 memory:ff9f0000-ff9fffff
```

What can I do to make it work every time?

Comment: Most likely a hardware issue. Posting the kernel log could be useful: `/var/log/dmesg`.

Comment: Here it is: [link](http://pastebin.com/nSD5B1XV)